# Angular custom validator error group is deprecated: This API is not typesafe

Tags: angular, angular-validator

I've got this warning

> group is deprecated: This API is not typesafe and can result in issues
> with Closure Compiler renaming. Use the `FormBuilder#group` overload
> with `AbstractControlOptions` instead. Note that
> `AbstractControlOptions` expects `validators` and `asyncValidators` to
> be valid validators. If you have custom validators, make sure their
> validation function parameter is `AbstractControl` and not a
> sub-class, such as `FormGroup`. These functions will be called with an
> object of type `AbstractControl` and that cannot be automatically
> downcast to a subclass, so TypeScript sees this as an error. For
> example, change the `(group: FormGroup) => ValidationErrors|null`
> signature to be `(group: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors|null`.

How can I fix this code?

```
export function passwordMatchValidator(
  group: AbstractControl
): { invalidRePassword: boolean } | null {
  const passwordCtrl: AbstractControl | null = group.get('password');
  const passwordConfirmCtrl: AbstractControl | null = group.get(
    'passwordConfirm'
  );
  if (passwordCtrl && passwordConfirmCtrl) {
    if (passwordConfirmCtrl.touched || passwordConfirmCtrl.dirty) {
      if (passwordCtrl.value !== passwordConfirmCtrl.value) {
        passwordConfirmCtrl.setErrors({ invalidRePassword: true });
        return { invalidRePassword: true };
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

this.frm = this.fb.group({
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    passwordConfirm: ['', Validators.required],
    },
    { validator: passwordMatchValidator }
);
```